# Woo-commerce Product Image open direct image url instead of lightbox

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am having issue with Woocommerce product page image. The image of the product page if clicked if opening the image path and does not return to the product page.

Is, there anyway I can open the image as a popup on click or deactivate the clickable image.

Comment: @Syntax_Error

Hi, The theme is Woocommerce compatible. My support is expired as they support only for a year. I have not uploaded any new plugin. 2) I don't want to add any new plugin. Can you please let me know where to add the codes you have mentioned or option where I can make the image unable to open on click.

Comment: What i asked is that if  its compatible with the newer Woocommerce version 3.0, because a lot of changes were made in that version and that could be the main problem. The code goes in your function.php file, i suggest you read this https://createandcode.com/broken-photo-gallery-and-lightbox-after-woocommerce-3-0-upgrade/

Comment: @Syntax_Error I Tried to add those code in the child theme function.php but, it broke the site. Also, tried the css but, the result was same. Is there any way I can disable click on image?

Comment: In that case i recommend just installing the plug-in

Answer (score 2):

I’m new to woocommerce but I think that you are refering to is the Lighbox, you need to check first is if your Theme is compatible with Woocommerce 3.0
or what happened before the Image Viewer become incompatible? you update something? you install a new plugin?

Anyway you can do this.

**1.-Get Support from the Theme Developer.**

If you have a premium theme you can ask the developer about this issue, I’m sure there must be some kind of update or solution they have already,

**2.- Add Support to Woocommerce 3.0**

Sometimes I see you can add the light box functions manually with this code.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_setup' );

function yourtheme_setup() {
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```

**3.- Use a Plug-In (as a temporary solution)**.

I don't recommend this because the Woocommerce core has to already have this. But while you search for another solution, you can use this as temporary. (It happened to me already, when a Marketing Business update the woo-core of a Site I was managing, and they didn't fix it, so i have to install a plug-in as a temporary solution because my boss wanted a "fast" solution. that fixed later updating the theme anyway). Anyway, [the one i use is this one](https://huge-it.com/lightbox/).

*I Hope some of this options can help you with your problem.*

Answer (score 1):

Just install a Light box plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-lightbox/ and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by selecting **new woocomerce lightbox 3.0 lightbox** as the product image lightbox

This option is under **Customize ▸ WooCommerce
Product Page ▸ Gallery ▸ product image lightbox**

Before this fix, the lightbox option selected was from my activated flatsome theme.

[image]